# How to display blob image in <td>

Tags: php

Here's my database connection code.

I want to display the blob image into td

```
<?php while ($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($content))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$news['<img src = "data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'"/>'].  "</td>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$news['title']."</td>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$news['content']."</td>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$news['date']."</td>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" .$news['author']."</td>";
                echo "</td>";
            }

            ?>
```

and I got a error says undefined index

Comment: Do a var_dump of $news and check if you are getting the result.. if so .. use a foreach loop instead of while loop

Comment: You are trying to display a cell called `'<img src = "data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'"/>'`. I don't think that's correct. The error says there is no index like that in your array.

Comment: @AdamBenedek when I do .$news ['cover']. it display the image by text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Change your line :

`echo "<td>" .$news['<img src = "data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($img).'"/>'].  "</td>";`

By

`echo "<td><img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($news['img'])."'/></td>";`

Comment: I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'src' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I copy and paste your code and change the img to cover (fied name of blob) and it works thanks mate

Comment: how can I resize the image in php?

Comment: Look at GD extension : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php. You can also add height and width attributes on your img tag, but client will download original picture with a potentially big size